# How to add user_id in form params in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this model, called `products`, that has an `id`, `user_id` and `product_name`.
I have a simple `form_for` to pass to my `product_controller` the `product_name` param. In this same controller, I have access to the `current_user`, which I have to pass in order to create a new `Product`.
The problem is that the `user_id` always has to be the current user logged in, so I can't allow the user to send me this param in my `form_for`, thus I can't `permit` it as well.
What I'm doing right now is to create a new hash with the `user_id` param, and merge the params that comes from the `form`.

`products_controller.rb:`

```
  def create
    product_user_id_param = { "user_id": current_user.id.to_s }
    @product = Product.new(product_user_id_param.merge(params[:product_name]))
    ...
  end
```

Is there a more convenient or Rails way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create you product with you current_user reference, this is the more convenient way in my opinion:

```
current_user.produtcs.create(name: params[:product_name])
```

But, to above code works, you have to construct you relations correctly, like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belogs_to :user
end
```

Now, you can do it!

You can read more about it, in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/association_basics.html, the docs recommeds this way!

Answer (score 4):

Solution #1

Product has `user_id` which means `product belongs_to :user` and `user has_many :products`

Hence it can be written as

```
current_user.products.new(product_name: params[:product_name])
```

Solution#2

Set current_user explicitly

```
@product = Product.new(product_name: params[:product_name])
@product.user_id = current_user.id
#@product.user = current_user
@product.save
```